# How to store strings in external file for app-wide use (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, string, nsstring

I am creating an iOS app that, as part of its functionality, loads many web pages in a UIWebView.

For ease of editing and grouping, I would like to list each URL String in an external file, and then access that string within the app.  For example, the string file could look like:

```
NSString *google = @"http://www.google.com";
NSString *stackOverflow = @"http://www.stackoverflow.com";
NSString *cnn = @"http://www.cnn.com";
NSString *facebook = @"https://www.facebook.com"
```

and in the core application code, I would tell the UIWebview to load the URL contained in `stackOverflow`.  That way, if StackOverflow ever decided to change their URL (this is a hypothetical example), I could easily change the URL in the external strings file, and not bother with the core application code.

How would I do so?  I know there is a "Strings file" in Xcode, but I think that is only used for language localization.

Comment: Although strings files are useful for localization, I think there is nothing wrong with using them outside localization context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even for loading non-localized string resources, you use the same infrastructure you do for localizing strings. So for iOS if you put a WebLinks.strings file at the top level of your application bundle it will be treated as the non-localized version of the strings resource. Whenever you use any of the system functions to retrieve a localized string if no appropriate localized string resource is found, the bundle’s loading code automatically chooses the appropriate non-localized string instead. Thus for example you could setup WebLinks.strings like a standard .strings file in the top level of your application bundle with lines like:

```
/* Google's URL */
"googleURL" = "http://www.google.com";
```

You could use the following code to retrieve a string:

```
NSString *google = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"googleURL", @"WebLinks", @"Google's URL");
```

Comment: I've finally finished changing the code around for a .strings file and it is working great. Thanks a bunch.